# Need C++ assistance, Score Keeping Code Not Working Properly

Tags: c++

For my mid term project im creating a program that randomly generates number and the user is prompted to subtract the numbers and input their answer, also in the code, I would like to keep track of their current score, but for some reason the score is not being updated where is all of the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
A:

srand(time(0));

int number1 = rand() % 10;
int number2 = rand() % 10;
int answer;
int correctAnswer;
int score = 0;

if (number1 < number2)
{
    int temp = 0;
    temp = number2;
    number2 = number1;
    number1 = temp;
}


system("CLS");
cout << "Current Score: " << score << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "What is " << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = ";
cin >> answer;

correctAnswer = number1 - number2;

if (answer == correctAnswer)
{
    cout << "Good Job!" << endl;
    score = score + 1;
    system("Pause");
    goto A;
} 
else 
{
    cout << "Incorrect. The Correct Answer is " << correctAnswer <<endl; 
    cout << "Try Again" << endl;
    score = (score * 0);
    goto A;
}


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Clarify](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26390786/edit), [clarify](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26390786/edit), and then [clarify](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26390786/edit) again!

Comment: Wow!  Using `goto` in a midterm project, how bold!

Comment: What do you want? please, could you be more specific

Comment: How does the execution get to the `return` statement?  Both clauses of the `if` statement `goto` the `A` label.  Turn up the warnings on your compiler.  You should see some warnings about dead code.

Comment: Replace `score = (score * 0);` to `score = 0;`.  Simpler less confusing.

Comment: Replace your swap code with `std::swap`, you can read about it at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sweet thanks, I never thought about it like that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GOTO statement is sending you to the top of your program where you set score = 0... that's why you're not seeing score increase.

Move the following line:

```
int score = 0;
```

above your "A:" label.

Comment: How about not use `goto` at all.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I'm assuming (by the level of coding) that the instructor has not taught looping structures yet.

Comment: Well, you can become the unofficial teacher and show what the code should be without goto.

Comment: Or, you could just answer his specific question and let the instructor do his job... according to his own plan.

Comment: I dunno @PaulMcKenzie. When I was in school I was told I would lose points if I did anything the instructor hadn't taught yet. That's the assumption I went with at least.

Comment: @BoltBait Thank you very much for your help its working great now

Comment: This is scraping the bottom of the barrel where a C++ loop construct is introdcued by a teacher by using `goto`.

Comment: @ScottRenner, glad you got it working.  Have fun in class!  Don't be dissuaded by the haters around here.  Go ahead and post any questions you have about your assignments. SOME of us are always willing to help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My instructor hasn't introduced loop structures yet so instead of trying to teach my self how to do them, goto just seemed easier

Comment: @ScottRenner - I understand.  However, when you do get to looping structures, you will put away the goto, hopefully for a very long time.  Since your program loops forever (did you fix that?), then you can replace the goto with a `while(true) { .. your code ... }` instead of the `A:` label and the `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: don't use goto. It isn't generally considered good practice and can make your code not maintainable. Second, you are initializing your variable in your goto, so every pass it is set to 0 before you  print it off.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int score = 0;

A:

srand(time(0));

int number1 = rand() % 10;
int number2 = rand() % 10;
int answer;
int correctAnswer;


if (number1 < number2)
{
    int temp = 0;
    temp = number2;
    number2 = number1;
    number1 = temp;
}


system("CLS");
cout << "Current Score: " << score << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "What is " << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = ";
cin >> answer;

correctAnswer = number1 - number2;

if (answer == correctAnswer)
{
    cout << "Good Job!" << endl;
    score = score + 1;
    system("Pause");
    goto A;
} 
else 
{
    cout << "Incorrect. The Correct Answer is " << correctAnswer <<endl; 
    cout << "Try Again" << endl;
    score = (score * 0);
    goto A;
}


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```